# QProgressDialog does not display immediately

Tags: qt, modal-dialog, progressdialog

I have a `QProgressDialog` that I want to display immediately

```
QProgressDialog *progress = new QProgressDialog("Downloading files...", 
  "Cancel", 0, 2*selection.size()+1);
progress->setMinimumDuration(0);
progress->setWindowModality(Qt::WindowModal);
progress->setValue(0);
```

Then I run a `for` loop with the task and finally assign the maximum value:

```
for (int i = 1; i < selection.size()+1; ++i) 
{
  progress->setValue(2*i-1);
  if (progress->wasCanceled())
    break;
  do_half_task();
  progress->setValue(2*i);
  if (progress->wasCanceled())
    break;
  do_second_half();
}
progress->setValue(2*selection.size()+1);
```

But with this code, the dialog window borders appear, transparents without any widgets inside, and only gets filled with the label and progressbar when a full for loop has completed.

I think this is because only after a full loop has completed is that Qt can compute the duration of each step, and check that it will be `>0` which I am setting as minimum duration. However, from the docs I see

> minimumDuration : int
>
> If set to 0, the dialog is always shown as soon as any progress is set. The default is 4000 milliseconds.

From where I would've expected the dialog to show up immediately in the first loop pass after setting `progress->setValue(1)`.

How can I get my `QProgressDialog` to appear immediately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this matches for Qt too
but in C# if you run the execution of your code in the same thread like

```
ProcessBar p = new ProcessBar();
this.Controls.Add(p);
...
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  p.Value = i;
  Thread.Sleep(1);
}
```

then you have the problem that your Form does not get to the code where it is redrawn.

Maybe try making your execution loop in a nother thread?

Answer (score 2):

When you make the main thread go into a loop, it can't do any event processing until the loop ends and your method returns.

So it can only process all "paint update" requests once you are done.

You can call `QCoreApplication::processEvents()` inside the loop to allow it to return to event processing for a while.

Comment: `setValue()` already calls `processEvents()` I'm working in implementing the loop in a different thread using `QtConcurrent` as per @MaddinTribleD recomendation, but it's a little tricky because my data is on an non-concurrent tree. I'll accept that answer if it turns out that looping in a different thread solves the issue.

Answer (score 2):

To show the dialog immediately then just call `QProgressDialog::show()`.